# How to Remove Subclassed SKNode from Memory?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created a "SPriteKitButton" SKNode subclass in a separate Swift file to use in SpriteKit to make custom button-like objects. I initialize a new button like so:

```
self.homeButton = SpriteKitButton(buttonUnpressedImage: "homeUnpressed.png", buttonPressedImage: "homePressed.png", buttonName: "homeButton", scale: 1, buttonAction: returnHome)
self.addChild(homeButton)
```

The button works great, but when I use presentScene to change scenes, the SpriteKitButton subclass is not being removed from memory. I am using the contentsOfFile method to set the textures in the subclass. I call

```
homeButton.removeFromParent
```

in willMoveFromView, but after testing I have found that my buttons are staying in memory and adding a small ~1-2 mb with each scene change.

I'm not experienced with using subclassed objects in SpriteKit, so how would I make sure my custom buttons get deleted when the scene is changed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.homeButton = nil
```

Use this if you are using strong references

Comment: This actually produces a crash.

Comment: Never mind this does work...I had a typo in willMoveFromView in which I set another button to nil and then called removeFromParent after that, which caused the crash. After removing removeFromParent it works perfectly.